# Помогите нужно было создать аналог функции Object.create не проходит один тест

Tags: javascript, объекты

```
    Object.create = function (prototype, properties) {
        let result = {};
        if (prototype !== Object(prototype) && prototype !== null) {
            throw new TypeError("");
        }
        if (prototype === null) {
            return result;
        }
         result = Object.setPrototypeOf({}, prototype);
        if (properties !== undefined) {
            Object.defineProperties(result, properties);
        }
        return result;
```

}

```
✕ должен возвращать пустой объект при вызове с аргументом null (29ms)
✓ аргумент `prototype` отрабатывает должным образом (5ms)
✓ аргумент `properties` отрабатывает должным образом (3ms)
✓ объект A должен является прототипом объекта B (3ms)
✓ объекты A и B должны быть разными (3ms)
✓ без аргументов должна быть ошибка TypeError (2ms)
✓ если первый параметр не является объектом или null, то должна быть 
   ошибка TypeError (1ms)
```

Comment: что значит "пустой объект"? С какими именно параметрами происходит вызов и какой результат ожидается?

Comment: В функцию передается объект как аргумент. Этот преданный объект должен стать прототипом нового объекта если в аргумент предать null то функция должна вернуть пустой объект

Comment: _что значит "пустой объект"?_

Comment: ну обычный объект без свойств и методов

Comment: но с прототипом?

Comment: без прототипа думаю

Comment: тогда у тебя ошибка ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ `if (prototype === null) {
            return result;
        }` ты возвращаешь с протоипом

Comment: а как можно вернуть объект без прототипа

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: установить ему `null` в качестве прототипа

Answer (score 1):

стоит убрать эту строчку, эта проверка тебе не нужна.

```
if (prototype === null){
    return result;
}
```

На твоем месте я бы после объявления переменной result сделал проверку на properties, должно сработать)

```
if (properties === null) {
    return result;
}
```